# Issue with Sanity Next.js Live preview mode

Tags: typescript, next.js, content-management-system, sanity

I am trying to implement live preview mode for the blogs on my Next.js website. I followed all the steps mentioned in the Sanity docs (https://www.sanity.io/guides/nextjs-live-preview) and to integrated preview mode as an iframe using this guide (https://www.sanity.io/plugins/iframe-pane), But preview mode is not working in either of them i.e via Iframe inside Sanity Studio or via Next.js /api/preview route.
Note. I have integrated Sanity inside Next.js app, so sanity is running on http://localhost:3000/studio.

The only difference between the above mentioned guide and mine is I am rendering my blogs in /blogs route instead of homepage. I hope that's doesn't make much of a difference but still I am getting this error though I have signed in uisng Google OAuth in this route

[image]